# Change image icon when the active tab is change

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Current I have a v-tab that have four tabs with image icon and text as well. But when the tab is active, the active tab icon should change to another image. How should I made it?

```
<v-tabs v-model="tabs" class="tabs-menu">
    <v-tab
      v-for="item in items"
      :key="item.id"
    >
      <img :src="item.icon" />
        {{ item.name }}
    </v-tab>
</v-tabs>

data() {
    return {
      tabs: null,
      items: [
        { icon: "/planeInactive.svg", name: "plane" },
        { icon: "/hotelInactive.svg", name: "hotel" },
        { icon: "/planehotelInactive.svg", name: "plane + hotel" },
        { icon: "/planeInactive.svg", name: "students" },
      ],
    };
  },
```

Comment: What is the vuetify version?

Comment: the vuetify version is vue2

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "the icon should change"? Do you mean to use another icon or the icon's color should change when the tab is active?

Comment: yea if the tab is active the image icon be like icon: "/FlightsActive.svg" if not the image icon will remain inactive. For example if I click for the student tabs; the student image icon shud be icon: "/FlightsActive.svg" while all other icon is "/...Inactive.svg"

Answer (score 0):

1. Use some default value for your `v-model`, `'tab'` to make a tab active by default. (*I am using the name property of the tab in `v-model` but you can use any unique property you want.*)
2. Use this `v-model` to check which tab is active and using the condition operator, update the icon. (*I used dummy icons you can use yours.*)

Here's the demo where you should see that when the tab is active, the colorful flight icon would show otherwise black flight icon would be displayed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <v-app>
        <v-main>
          <v-container>
            <v-tabs
              v-model="tab"
              >
              <v-tab
                v-for="(item, index) in items"
                :key="index"
                :href="`#${item.name}`"
                class="home-tabs"
                active-class="activeTab"
                >
                <img :src="tab == item.name ? item.icon : inactive_icon" />
                {{ item.name }}
              </v-tab>
            </v-tabs>
          </v-container>
        </v-main>
      </v-app>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data () {
      return {
        tab: 'Flights',
        inactive_icon: 'https://www.svgrepo.com/show/413929/fly.svg',
        items: [
          { icon: "https://www.svgrepo.com/show/424654/airplane-flight-travel.svg", name: "Flights" },
          { icon: "https://www.svgrepo.com/show/424654/airplane-flight-travel.svg", name: "Hotels" },
          { icon: "https://www.svgrepo.com/show/424654/airplane-flight-travel.svg", name: "Flights + Hotels" },
          { icon: "https://www.svgrepo.com/show/424654/airplane-flight-travel.svg", name: "Students" },
        ],
      }
      },
        vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
</html>
```